# Nokia 950 XL and encryption

Tags: security, lumia-950-xl

Does Windows 10 on-board Microsoft Lumia 950 XL comes with enabled / available disk (memory) encryption? If not, is there any way to get it (i.e. like purchasing Win 10 Pro license etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 Mobile (as shipping on the Lumia 950/XL) does come with a setting for Device encryption which "helps protect your files and folders from unauthorised access in case you device is lost or stolen"